# Passing PHP variabe in Sweet alert 2

Tags: javascript, php, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I want to display the PHP variable in sweet alert but unable to find the solution, I went through the documentations of sweet alert 2 but couldn't find anything.
Can anyone help me?

here's my code

```
$name = "xyz";

//sweetalert code
echo "<script>";
echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Greetings $name!","Thank you for adding your business details.<br>Our admin team will review the same and will publish shortly..!","success");';
echo '}, 100);</script>';
```

Comment: https://limonte.github.io/sweetalert2/ refer it and why dont you use ?> clean html code here <?php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to switch the quotes:

```
echo "setTimeout(function () { swal('Greetings $name!','Thank you for adding your business details.<br>Our admin team will review the same and will publish shortly..!','success');'";
```

Or, another option, concatenate variables within string:

```
echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Greetings ' . $name . '!","Thank you for adding your business details.<br>Our admin team will review the same and will publish shortly..!","success");';
```

---

When you include a variable inside echo, you need to use `"`

Know difference between `"` and `'` another [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3446245/5447994)

---

Answer (score 0):

You need to concatenate it, try to use the following:

```
echo 'setTimeout(function () { swal("Greetings"'.$name.'"!","Thank you for adding your business details.<br>Our admin team will review the same and will publish shortly..!","success");';
```